# How to build requirejs app with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a requirejs app which gets loaded from the require config pasted below. The path references to the vendor directory are 3rd party libraries loaded via bower.

```
// Require.js Configurations
// -------------------------
require.config({
  baseUrl: './js/app',

  paths: {
    'backbone'            : '../../vendor/backbone/backbone',
    'backbone.paginator'  : '../../vendor/backbone.paginator/lib/backbone.paginator',
    'backbone.validateAll': '../../vendor/Backbone.validateAll/src/javascripts/Backbone.validateAll.js',
    'backbone.wreqr'      : '../../vendor/backbone.wreqr/lib/backbone.wreqr.js',
    'handlebars'          : '../../vendor/handlebars/handlebars.runtime',
    'handlebars-helpers'  : '../../vendor/handlebars-helpers/src/helpers',
    'jasminejquery'       : '../../vendor/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery',
    'jquery'              : '../../vendor/jquery/dist/jquery',
    'jquerymobile'        : '../../vendor/jquery-mobile-bower/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5',
    'loglevel'            : '../../vendor/loglevel/lib/loglevel',
    'marionette'          : '../../vendor/marionette/lib/backbone.marionette',
    'modernizr'           : '../../vendor/modernizr/modernizr',
    'moment'              : '../../vendor/moment/moment',
    'swiper'              : '../../vendor/swiper/dist/idangerous.swiper',
    'templates/jst'       : '../../build/tmp/templates/jst-build',
    'underscore'          : '../../vendor/lodash/dist/lodash'
  },

  shim: {
    'backbone.validateAll'  : ['backbone'],
    'jasminejquery'         : ['jquery'],
    'jquerymobile'          : ['jquery'],
    'modernizr'             : { exports: 'Modernizr' },
    'swiper'                : ['jquery']
  }
});

// Bootstraps
require(['bootstrap/backbone'], function(){});
require(['bootstrap/jquery'], function(){});

// App
require(['init/Main'], function(main) {});
```

The issue I'm getting in my console says that my bootstrap files are not found which only leads me to believe that webpack is not loading in my `require.config`.

> > $ webpack ./app/config/requirejs.js ../build/test.js Hash: f33deaf4b2ff288e08b6 Version: webpack 1.5.3 Time: 61ms   Asset  Size 
> >     Chunks             Chunk Names test.js  2435       0  [emitted]  main 
> >     [0] ./app/config/requirejs.js 1691 {0} [built] [3 errors]
>
> ERROR in ./app/config/requirejs.js Module not found: Error: Cannot
>   resolve module 'bootstrap/backbone' in
>   /Users/glitches/Sites/public/js/app/config  @
>   ./app/config/requirejs.js 35:0-45
>
> ERROR in ./app/config/requirejs.js Module not found: Error: Cannot
>   resolve module 'bootstrap/jquery' in
>   /Users/glitches/Sites/public/js/app/config  @
>   ./app/config/requirejs.js 36:0-43
>
> ERROR in ./app/config/requirejs.js Module not found: Error: Cannot
>   resolve module 'init/Main' in
>   /Users/glitches/Sites/public/js/app/config  @
>   ./app/config/requirejs.js 39:0-41

I'm guessing I need to rewrite my requirejs configuration as an entry point but I'm asking here incase anyone has a better idea of how to go about this.

Comment: You don't have `bootstrap/backbone` or `bootstrap/jquery` module defined. `require(['init/Main', 'backbone'], function(main, Backbone){})` with backbone `shimmed`

Comment: @Sami - Both `bootstrap/backbone`  and `bootstrap/jquery` are modules that I created that just do some configuring. They are not twitter bootstrap related and they do exist. For example, `bootstrap/backbone` looks like this `define(['backbone', 'backbone.paginator'], function(backbone, paginator){ /* do something */ });`. This file lives in *app/bootstrap/backbone* and loads fine with requirejs. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your require statements are trying to resolve as modules in your *node_modules* folder, because there is no absolute or relative path.

[How modules are resolved, depending on path type.](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/resolving)

If you are requiring files within your application's source, use a relative or absolute path.

```
// Bootstraps
require(['../bootstrap/backbone'], function(){});
require(['../bootstrap/jquery'], function(){});

// App
require(['../init/Main'], function(main) {});
```

This assumes a structure where this is at */app/config/requirejs.js* and your target modules are at */app/bootstrap/backbone.js*, */app/bootstrap/jquery.js*, and */app/init/Main.js*.